# IS it possible to get real-time updates for friend requests?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, real-time

The real time doc [page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) doesn't mention friend requests, so i was wondering if an app can get real time updates if a user has a new friend request?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to use the Message object since friend requests now come through the message box.

Answer (score 0):

Directly from [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/):

> **friendrequests**     The user's incoming friend requests.

Special permissions may be needed

Comment: as you can read [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) it says: "Not all ... connections of the user object can be subscribed to... list of User connections to which you can subscribe: feed, friends, activities, interests, music, books, movies, television, likes, checkins. You can't subscribe to these User connections yet: home, tagged, posts, photos, albums, videos, groups, notes, events, inbox, outbox, updates, accounts.We will add support for more properties and connections in the future".  **So** the friendrequests is not mentioned in the can or can't list.